# How to return value from Android PhoneStateListener?

Tags: java, android

I want to get currently cell information in use for data transmit. Before Android Q, I can get it easily via [getallcellinfo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/telephony/TelephonyManager?hl=en#getallcellinfo). However, beginning with Android Q, this will be reported via [onCellInfoChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener#oncellinfochanged).

I don't need to listen on the changed of cell information, I just need the cell information at the moment that the method is called. I cannot just return `((CellInfoLte) cellInfo).getCellIdentity().getEarfcn();` inside PhoneStateListener. How to implement this?

```
public int getEarfcn() {
  telephonyManager.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCellInfoChanged(List<CellInfo> cellInfoList) {
      super.onCellInfoChanged(cellInfoList);
      for (CellInfo cellInfo : cellInfoList) {
        if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoLte) {
          int earfcn = ((CellInfoLte) cellInfo).getCellIdentity().getEarfcn();
          // How to return this "earfcn" once I get it?
        }
      }
    }
  }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
  return CellInfo.UNAVAILABLE;
}
```

Comment: I think that this is a XY problem http://xyproblem.info/ because you can get the value inside your object with a variable inside the Main class, and after check if this variable is null or have some value!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use return. Create an interface same

```
public voi getEarfcn(ICellInfoChanged cellInfoChangedCallback) {
  telephonyManager.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCellInfoChanged(List<CellInfo> cellInfoList) {
      super.onCellInfoChanged(cellInfoList);
      for (CellInfo cellInfo : cellInfoList) {
        if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoLte) {
          int earfcn = ((CellInfoLte) cellInfo).getCellIdentity().getEarfcn();
          cellInfoChangedCallback.onCallback(cellInfo);
        }
      }
    }
  }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}
```

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'getEarfcn' in 'CellIdentityLte'? any suggestion !